# Select the column down to the first blank row in the adjacent column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010 I have several columns with data.  I insert a column, and type a formula in the top cell of that column.  I want to fill the formula into the remainder of the column, down to the same row as is filled for the other columns.  Once the selection is made, I could use Paste, or Ctrl + D to fill down.  My issue is with selecting row 1-N quickly (without the mouse).

Think of a sheet with 10k rows or more.  My current inadequate solutions are:

1. Use the mouse by scrolling and shift clicking on the last cell
2. Use the arrow key while holding shift until reaching the last cell
3. Use the page down key while holding shift until reaching the last cell
4. Double click the formula cell handle to fill down (uses mouse)
5. Ctrl + T to make it a table, then Ctrl + Space to select the data, then have to change it back from a table

Ctrl + Shift + Down works if the column has data in it, but if the column is empty it goes to the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: I would go with #5, why do you "have to change it back from a table"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Move to the column that has the data
2. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to move to the last row
3. Move to the column you want to fill
4. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>
5. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to fill the column.